# Why are my variables undefined outside of the callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some variables that I am setting withing a function. When inside the function I can get, set and alert the `uid1` and `accessToken2`, but if I try to alert them outside of the function, it gives `undefined`. How can I set the values?

Here is the code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid1 = response.authResponse.userID;
        alert(uid1); //works here
        var accessToken2 = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert(accessToken2); //works here
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { } 
    else { }
});

alert(uid1); //does NOT work here
alert(accessToken2); //does NOT work here
```

Comment: For future readers, I suggest this question be edited to reflect that the variables are set inside a callback function.  As written, it looks like variable scope is the only issue.  Variable scope is one of two issues relevant in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared those variables outside of the scope that you're using them. To fix your code, declare them outside of the function:

```
var uid1 = "";
var accessToken2 = "";
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        uid1 = response.authResponse.userID;
        alert(uid1);
        accessToken2 = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert(accessToken2);
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

    } else {

    }

    alert(uid1); // Values will be set here.
    alert(accessToken2);
});
alert(uid1); // Values won't reliably be set here.
alert(accessToken2);
```

**Update:** As suggested by the comments below, because your `getLoginStatus` method is asynchronous, you will likely not have values when you call the `alert()` outside the method. I have added additional alerts inside the call back to show where you should try to access the values.

Comment: This won't work either because the value of uid1 won't be filled in when the alert runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 the values won't be set, but it fixes the `undefined` problem, as in the variables will exist.

Comment: @Autolycus - why did you select this answer?  It won't work reliably.  The values of `uid1` and `accessToken2` are only valid in the callback function and in any code you call from there.  `getLoginStatus()` can be asynchronous which means that the callback is called some time later.

Comment: @Autolycus In particular, if FB.getLoginStatus is asynchronous then uid1, accessToken2 aren't set until the callback function has executed.  This is a logical problem rather than just a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are thinking about your code as if the callback function is executed before the

```
alert(uid1); //does NOT work here
alert(accessToken2);
```

Since FB.getLoginStatus may be asynchronous, this isn't the case.  It will return and continue with your alerts immediately.  The problem here isn't just variable scope.  The problem is that you don't have access to the information you want to display until the callback is executed.  You can't program your way out of that by moving the variable declaration around.  You have to accommodate this fact of reality in your design of the program/website/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Javascript have function scope. Meaning they only exist in the function they are declared in with the var keyword, unless they are global variables. Move the var keyword out of your function, but to avoid making them global wrap it within another function like this:

```
(function(){
    var uid1, accessToken2;
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            uid1 = response.authResponse.userID;
          alert(uid1); works here
            accessToken2 = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            alert(accessToken2); //works here
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

          } else {

          }
         });
    alert(uid1);  //uid1 declared but not set until callback executes
    alert(accessToken2); //accessToken2 declared but not set until callback executes
    // these alerts will likely NOT display the information
    // they are intended to display because of asynchronous callback 
})();

alert(uid1);  //uid1 is not declared, so this doesn't work
alert(accessToken2); //accessToken2 is not declared, so this doesn't work
```

Comment: This won't work either because the value of uid1 won't be filled in when the alert runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is `FB.getLoginStatus` asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, FB.getLoginStatus can be async (sometimes the result is cached).  That's why it takes a callback.  If it wasn't async, they would just return the result rather than use a callback.

Answer (score -3):

Because JavaScript (along with all programming languages *ever*) has scope?

Comment: Snarky answers don't really help