# how to fill an array outside the function clause in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to fill an array outside the function block

```
app.get('/getpackages/:dateStart/:dateEnd/:limit', function (req, res) {
  var xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz = []
  var xlsSourceFilesRetrievedSvn = []

  var dateStart = req.params.dateStart;
  var dateEnd = req.params.dateStart;
  var limit = Number(req.params.limit);
  
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM summary_dz WHERE Start != "" AND  Start BETWEEN ? AND ? LIMIT ?'
  db.query(sql, [dateStart,dateEnd,limit], function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (const counter in results) {  
      xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz.push(results[counter].XlsSourceFile);
    }
    // console.log(xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz)
  });
  console.log(xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz)
```

I want to fill `xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz`. Whats wrong with what i wrote? I get an emty array. The console.log inside the block in comment gives the wanted result How can the from outside the block?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in it. It is an expected behavior of Javascript.  The console.log statement is executed before even your db query is completed. As the execution is asynchronous, the control doesn't wait for things to be ready.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my variables undefined outside of the callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459280/why-are-my-variables-undefined-outside-of-the-callback-function)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that's a normal behaviour of javascript. I just needed a way to wait until the results are ready so that i can make analysis to it. Maybe there is a best practice for this but I didn't know what to do exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this should works:

```
app.get('/getpackages/:dateStart/:dateEnd/:limit', async (req, res) => {
  var xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz = []
  var xlsSourceFilesRetrievedSvn = []
  const promiseQuery = (sql, dateStart, dateEnd, limit) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=> {
      db.query(sql, [dateStart,dateEnd,limit], function (err, results) {
        if (err) rej(err);
        res(results)
      });
    })
  }

  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM summary_dz WHERE Start != "" AND  Start BETWEEN ? AND ? LIMIT ?'

  const dateStart = req.params.dateStart;
  const dateEnd = req.params.dateStart;
  const limit = Number(req.params.limit);
  
 
  const results = await promiseQuery(sql, dateStart, dateEnd, limit)
  for (const counter in results) {  
    xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz.push(results[counter].XlsSourceFile);
  }

  console.log(xlsSourceFilesRetrievedTsdz)
  
}
```

What I do here was wrap the whole thing in a Promise and return it to wait te results.

Comment: I get this error:  
const results = await promisQuery(sql, dateStart, dateEnd, limit)
                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:139:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:236:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)

Comment: Sorry I forget to convert the function as promise, check it out again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need an explanation to something. I just get the final element of the table returned by the ```res(results)``` but i need the hole data. Is that hoy the promise works ??